# Advanced JavaScript split

Tags: javascript

I have to split this string here in JavaScript:

```
 hl=windows xp \"windows xp\"
```

to three words.

I used:

```
 keywords = keywords.split(/ /);
```

But then i got 4 words:

```
windows
xp
\"windows
xp\"
```

How could i split this string to just 3 words?

EDIT: and how do i remove the \".

Comment: what 3 words do you want?  -  Can you provide some examples?

Comment: presumably poster wants:  hl=windows, xp, "windows xp"

Comment: which four words are you seeing?

Comment: Do you have single quotes or double quotes around the string? The `hl=...` line is missing these quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a simple one:

```
keywords = keywords.match(/"[^"]*"|\w+/g).map(function(val) {
    if (val.charAt(0) == '"' && val.charAt(val.lenngth-1) == '"') {
        val = val.substr(1, val.length-2);
    }
    return val;
});
```

Comment: it works excellent. but how do u write it as a function so i can put a string and get out an array?

Comment: it didnt work on åäö and digits so i changed the \w to [a-öA-Ö0-9]

Comment: You can also use `\S` instead of `\w`.

Comment: is there an easy way of rewriting this to a function?

Comment: Put everything into a function like `function splitKeywords(keywords) { … }` and replace `keywords =` with `return`.

Answer (score 2):

```
function split(s, on) {
    var words = [];
    var word = "";
    var instring = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == on && !instring) {
            words.push(word);
            word = "";
        } else {
            if (c != '"')
                word += c;
        }
        if (c == '"') instring = !instring;
    }
    if (word != '') words.push(word); //dangling word problem solved
    return words;
}
```

and a usage example that fits the OP's example

```
var hl = "windows xp \"windows xp\"";
split(hl, " "); // returns ["windows","xp","windows xp"]
```

Comment: isnt it better to just use an appropiate regular expression in split()?

Comment: the problem with the regular expression approach is that your problem is not regular enough for regular expression to easily express.  fixed the dangling word issue, thats what i get for not testing

Answer (score 2):

```
hl="windows xp \"windows xp\""

var results = hl.split(/ /);

for(var s in results) {
    try {
        while (results[s].search("\"") > -1) {
            results.splice(s, 1);
        }
    } catch(e) {}
}

var quoted = hl.match(/"[^"]*"/g); //matches quoted strings

for(var s in quoted) {
    results.push(quoted[s]);
}

//results = ["windows", "xp", ""windows xp""]
```

edit, a one liner:

```
var results = hl.match(/\w+|"[^"]*"/g).map(function(s) {
    return s.replace(/^"+|"+$/g, "")
});
```

Comment: isnt it better to just use an appropiate regular expression in split()?

Comment: Believe it or not, some things are tricky to do with regexps (but see Gumbo's answer).

Comment: what does all the letters after the / do? eg /g. i cant find it in any regexp explanations

Comment: and how do i use your online if i got a string = "mac os" windows

Comment: It means that it is a global, basically find all matches in the string.

Comment: For reference RE: /g modifier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Regular_Expressions/Advanced_Searching_With_Flags